# Images from current directory are not being shown

Tags: php

I am trying to show all images from my current directory using php script. 
the php file which is showing image also is in the same directory.
here is the script

```
 <?php 
$dir =basename(__DIR__);
if (file_exists($dir) == false) 
{  
echo 'Directory \''. $dir. '\' not found!'; 
}
else{
$dir_contents = scandir($dir);  
foreach ($dir_contents as $file) 
 {     
 $file_type = strtolower(end(explode('.', $file)));    


if ($file !== '.' && $file !== '..' && in_array($file_type, $file_display) == true)
 {          
echo '<img src="'.$dir. '/'.$file. '" alt="'.$file. '" />';     }    }  }   
 ?>
```

the output says the no directory exists. but i have seen the directory exists. please tell me whats wrong with my code
Thanks

Comment: _whats wrong with my code_ Well to be honest, pretty much everything.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I have rewritten your script little bit. Using `glob()` to get files and `pathinfo()` to get file extension.

```
$files = glob(__DIR__.DIRECTORY_SEPARATOR.'*'); 
foreach ($files as $file) {
    if (!is_file($file)) { // if isn't file, skip it
        continue;
    }

    $info = pathinfo($file);
    // check if allowed extensions
    if (in_array(strtolower($info['extension']), array('jpg', 'png', 'gif'))) {
       echo ...; // your image echo
    }
}
```

If all images are for example `jpg`

```
$files = glob(__DIR__.DIRECTORY_SEPARATOR.'*.jpg');
```

And then skip parts with checking for extension.

Comment: Thanks @M. Kebza for your reply, i have used the above code but it show blank screen. here is the link for php file [link](http://palm-enterprise.net/eco/fashionwatch/19-8-2015/32392034303/images.php)

Comment: in image echo i did this echo '<img src="'.$file. '" alt="'.$file. '" />';   is that right?

Comment: On the link you provided i can see images... So it's everything ok?